# How do Light Foot attack and defend in Chainmail?

Tags: chainmail

I've recently purchased the pdf edition of Chainmail, the 1975 wargame by Gary Gygax* and Jeff Perren, and a friend of mine and I want to play a game soon.

One rule which I'd like some clarification on is about how these fatigued rules apply to Light Foot:

> A. They attack at the next lower value (heavy foot = light foot)
>
> B. They defend at the next lower value

I'm thinking that either

i. Nothing happens - there is no category lower than Light Foot, so we stop there

ii. They have to spend a turn not moving to lose their fatigued status.

Though I'm confused about how they are supposed to defend at the next lower value in any case.

---

* Of D&D Fame

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Combat Tables (p.40 of the 3rd edition) I would say:

A. They cannot attack. Light Foot already have only a 1/6 chance to kill any enemy troop type; anything worse would be below the resolution of the system. A generous referee might allow them to kill other Light Foot on a 6.

B. Add 1/6 to the "to be killed" chance. So Heavy Foot attacking Light Foot normally kill on a 5-6; attacking Fatigued Light Foot they'd kill them a 4-6.